# Can run ARM/rpi images in Docker on Windows but not linux

Tags: linux, docker, raspberry-pi, arm

I'm able to run the ARM images (eg. hypriot/rpi-node) in Docker on Windows (64bit), but in all linux x86/64 machines I've tried (Debian, CoreOS, Alpine etc) I get the following error - which makes sense to me but I dont get why it'd run in Docker on Windows then, and I wonder whether I'm missing some opportunity to use an x86 machine as a build server for ARM images (ie. the in google/aws cloud/azure). Any ideas how I might be able to?

```
docker run -ti hypriot/rpi-node ls
standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Comment: I had exactly the same question, did you get it answered? The answers below don't give me that satisfaction

Answer (score 5):

Docker for windows (and docker for mac) both use a linux vm to host containers. However, the difference between the linux vm they use and your linux machines is the fact that their VM has a kernel system called binfmt_misc setup to call qemu whenever it encounters a binary for a foreign architecture (https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit/blob/1c552f7a9db7f0660d3c83362d241e54142323ca/pkg/binfmt/etc/binfmt.d/00_linuxkit.conf )

If you were to configure your linux machine appropriately, it could be used as a build server for ARM images. Google `qemu-user-static` for some ideas of how to set it up.

Note that the linuxkit vm uses the 'F' flag which doesn't seem to be standard when configuring a typical linux environment. Without it, you need to put the qemu binary inside the container. I'm not sure why it isn't standard practice to use 'F' in more places (there does seem to be a debian bug to do so https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=868030 )

Answer (score 0):

On Windows and Mac docker works under Linux VM. So, I think, that for your container under Windows started ARM Linux VM. But under native Linux used native architecture.

Comment: I still dont quite get it - Docker on Windows runs a linux VM to host containers - Alpine linux I believe - this linux VM doesn't change whether you're running a x86-64 or ARM/rpi container - ie. in hyper-V there is only one machine, MobyLinuxVM, and it doesnt start/stop any others - so therefore there exists a linux which can run both on x64

Comment: You're actually right, no additional VMs are launched but the mobylinux VM does have qemu configured to handle arm seamlessly

Answer (score 0):

The "exec format error" confirms that you are not running your docker image on the correct architecture. 
I had this error trying to run a x86 docker image on a Raspberry Pi 2 (Which works with an ARM architecture). I am pretty sure it might be the same error when you do it the other way round.

So, as Kulti said, Windows/MAC must have started an ARM Linux VM.
If you wish to work with ARM docker images on Linux, you may want to try running a linux docker VM manually. I think you can do it using "docker-machine" even on linux : [Docker documentation for docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/). (Haven't done it myself so I am not sure)

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is only one VM and typically you can't use VMs to run code for one arcitecture (e.g. ARM) on a machine of another architecture (e.g. x86). For example, VirtualBox says [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Virtualization) that "Virtualizers such as VirtualBox, on the other hand, can achieve near-native performance for the guest code, but can only run guest code that was written for the same target hardware (such as 32-bit Linux on a 32-bit Windows host)"

Answer (score 0):

Docker on Windows uses a Linux VM which has been configured such that it can run images of other architectures through Qemu user mode emulation. You can configure native linux in a similar way and it too will then run ARM images. There is a well written three part series that describes it all in detail

Main thing to take away from [Part#1](https://ownyourbits.com/2018/05/23/the-real-power-of-linux-executables/) is that any file on Linux is executed through an interpreter (even binary files). The choice of interpreter is configurable, through [binfmt_misc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc), based on byte patterns at the beginning of file or filename extension etc.

[Part#2](https://ownyourbits.com/2018/06/13/transparently-running-binaries-from-any-architecture-in-linux-with-qemu-and-binfmt_misc/) builds on Part#1 to show how to configure Linux kernel (installed on any architecture) to interpret ARM binaries using [Qemu User Emulation](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation).

Finally [Part#3](https://ownyourbits.com/2018/06/27/running-and-building-arm-docker-containers-in-x86/) shows how to apply the same trick this time to a linux setup in a docker container which means that linux docker container (which could be for any architecture) will be able to execute ARM binaries.

Important thing to note here is that there is nothing special about docker implementation or containerization that allows docker on Windows to be able to execute ARM binaries. Instead any Linux setup (whether on bare metal or in a container) can be configured to execute ARM binaries through Qemu's user mode emulation of an ARM cpu.

Comment: The essential parts which covers full information is quite big to cut out and paste. I modified the answer to add logical summary and keywords and more links so that even if the links go dead these keywords and logical summary is enough to recover the exact procedure later on.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I will post my solution here in case someone came here through Google.

This happens because your Docker host is not able to run images with ARM architecture. To enable this in your Docker just run:

```
docker run --rm --privileged hypriot/qemu-register
```

You can find more info on this [post](https://blog.hypriot.com/post/docker-intel-runs-arm-containers/).

Answer (score 0):

You need the kernel configured for qemu's `binfmt_misc` module, and the container needs to have the static binaries used by qemu available inside the container filesystem.

You can load the files on the host with the `hyperiot/qemu-register` image, however I prefer the distribution vendor packages when available (ensures that I get patches when I update). For Debian, the imporant packages is `qemu-user-static` which you can install as root with:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install qemu-user-static
```

Ensure the kernel module is loaded (as root):

```
modprobe binfmt_misc
```

Then when running the container, you can mount the static qemu binaries into your container rather than packaging them inside your image, e.g. for the arm arch:

```
docker run -it --rm \
  -v /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static:/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static:ro \
  hypriot/rpi-node /bin/sh
```

Docker includes `binfmt_misc` in the embedded Linux VM's used on Docker for Desktop, and there appears to be some additional functionality to avoid the need to manually mount the static qemu files inside the container.