# How do I create a Docker container on a Windows 10 PC to run on a Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi, dockerfile

I am trying to create a Docker container to deploy onto a Raspberry Pi4. The container is to run a Python application. I'm building the container on a Windows 10 PC with the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "/app/main.py"]
```

Once I've built the container on the Windows PC, I'm pushing it to Docker Hub, then using `docker run` on the Raspberry Pi to pull the image and run it.

I understand that the architectures are different but I was under the impression the the `python:3.6-stretch` image pulled from Docker Hub was Multi-Arch and so would do the job. However when I try and run the image on the Raspberry Pi it fails with an 'exec format error' suggesting that the image is incorrect for the architecture.

What do I need to change in order to build the container on Windows and run it on Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the platform. Either in your Dockerfile, or from the command line.

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm/v7 python:3.6-stretch
```

You might need to use BuildKit or enable experimental features for your Docker daemon if you want to be able to set the platfrom from the command line:

```sh
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --platform=linux/arm/v7 .
```

You need to have Qemu and docker/binfmt installed to be able to build ARM images on x86_64. The installation process is explained here: https://www.docker.com/blog/getting-started-with-docker-for-arm-on-linux/

On Linux, you have to install this yourself. From [what I've gathered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39551573/6356744), it's included with Docker for Windows.

Comment: The addition of --platform to the docker file was sufficient. Thanks

Comment: @PeeGee if this resolved your problem, please accept this answer to mark the question as solved.