# Docker Image with Different Arch Works Just Fine, Why?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cpu-architecture, docker-machine, buildx

I am trying to figure out why a Docker image that I built using my Intel Macbook works on my M1 Macbook (It does spit out a warning about the platform but still runs).

On my Intel machine, I created a simple Python script, Dockerfile, and build and pushed the image.

```
# hello_world.py
def hello_world():
    print("hello world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_world()
```

For the Dockerfile...

```
FROM python:3.9-buster
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./hello_world.py /src/hello_world.py
CMD ["python3", "hello_world.py"]
```

For the build and push

```
$ docker build -t jduran9987/hello_world:single-arch .
$ docker push jduran9987/hello_world:single-arch
```

On DockerHub, the supported OS/ARCH says `linux/amd64` as expected.

[image]

However, I am able to successfully run the `hello_world.py` script on my M1 machine, though I do receive a warning about the different platforms.

[image]

I am confused because I was not expecting to be able to run the image on my M1 (`linux/arm64` arch). Can someone give me some insight into this?

- FYI, I know how to build multi-arch images, just confused as to why an image that was built using one arch works on another.

Comment: Presumably either an emulator is getting used transparently, or a native Python.  I don't know how Docker works, but one thing you could test is a binary executable (e.g. `gcc -static -o hello  hello.c`), instead of a Python program.  In your test, the only thing that's really specific to your docker image is the `hello_world.py` text file, which could be interpreted by either arch of Python interpreter.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39551573/596285

Comment: @BMitch Got it. So if qemu comes configured with Docker Desktop and is able to run different archs on a host machine, why the need for buildx? Is it just a matter of performance and getting rid of that pesky warning?

Comment: buildx isn't an emulator. If you create images for different platforms on the same host using buildx, that's because you have qemu configured to enable it. buildx gives you direct access to buildkit, including the ability to create multi-platform images, where most other build tools only create single platform images.

Comment: Thanks, @BMitch that makes sense. I'm still not sure what is causing me to be able to run my amd64 python image on an arm64 machine.

Comment: "Docker includes `binfmt_misc` in the embedded Linux VM's used on Docker for Desktop"